# Collatz and Printing with Spaces

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  const char* name = "COLLATZ";
  const int SIZE = 4096;
  int num = atoi(argv[1]);
  int shm_fd;
  void *ptr;
  shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
  ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
  ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
  pid_t id = fork();
if (id == 0) {
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR, 0666);
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    while (num != 1) {
        sprintf(ptr, "%d", num);
        ptr++;
        if (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2;
        else num = 3 * num + 1;
    }
    sprintf(ptr, "%d", num);
    ptr++;
} else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("PARENT: %s\n", (char*) ptr);
    shm_unlink(name);
}

return 0;
}
```

I would like for it to print with spaces between the correct numbers but haven't been able to figure that out like when adding `"%d "` or `" %d"` and some other formatting "things." When you run the program if you were to type in 8 I would expect the output to be: `8 4 2 1` but instead get `8421`. That being said, when we input a number like 19 we get a really long number that is "correct" but not formatted correctly. I would love some formatting assistance please!

Also it seems my algorithm might be incorrect - if you use 3 you should expect the result: `3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1` and I get `31518421`

Comment: Note that you'll get a buffer overflow (and probably a crash) if you search up to 1126015; that requires more than 4 KiB (4477 bytes plus a null or newline) to record the whole list of 528 numbers in the Collatz sequence.  You will also run into overflow before that. The max number in the sequence for 1,126,015 is 90,239,155,648 (which is too big for a 32-bit unsigned integer). The max value in the sequence for 77,671 is 1,570,824,736; the max for 113,383 is 2,482,111,348 which overflows signed 32-bit `int`; the max for 159,487 is 17,202,377,752 which overflows unsigned 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
sprintf(ptr, "%d ", num);
```

This will add a space after the number you are printing. YOu can read more about `printf` formatting at [printf doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

As per your incorrect result, you can see that if you take the first character of each number in: `3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1`, you get `31518421`. This is because you are only shifting `ptr` by 1 after printing in `ptr++;`. Hence if you printed two characters, the second one gets overwritten on the next step. What you need to do is:

```
int shift = sprintf(ptr, "%d ", num);
ptr = ptr + shift;
```

Or, in a more concise form:

```
ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%d ", num);
```

Here you shift the writer by the number of characters that were actually written, which will prevent then from being overwritten by the next call to sprintf.